# How to deal with different classes which have the same method?

Tags: c++

For example, I have 2 classes (in reality, it's more, that's why I'm asking this question) with the same methods:

```
class class1{
public:
    void init(){
        //something
    }
    void dostuff(){
        //something
    }
//
};

class class2{
public:
    void init(){
        //something
    }
    void dostuff(){
        //something
    }
//
};
```

And now a third one in which I want to deal with the two classes in the same manner:

```
class upclass{
public:
    upclass(class12* argclass){
    myclass=argclass;
    myclass->init();

    }
    void domorestuff(){
        myclass->dostuff();
    }
private:
    class12* myclass; //pointer to class 1 OR class 2
};
```

My question is now, do I need multiple constructors and multiple declarations to make it work or is there a way around it? Is it even possible to make "class12" a spacekeeper for these types without preprocessor-directives?

Comment: Seems to me that `class1` and `class2` should inherit from `upclass` and that the methods should be `virtual`, probably pure virtual in `upclass` and overriden in the  other classes. Maybe you can show how you intend to use the classes?

Comment: you need dynamic or static polymorphism. You need virtual methods or templates respectively.

Comment: There are enough possibilities with overloaded or templated constructors, and/or sharing an abstract baseclass between class1 and class2. Depends on what you want really.  if you derive class 1 and class 2 from the same abstract baseclass (interface) then you could just pass an instance to upclass (and you have dependency injection) which is great for unit testing.

Comment: Do you want a way to modify the classes? E.g. inheritance. Or a way to just call them? E.g. with templates. Make a class template by inserting `template<typename T>` before `class upclass`. Then you can use `T` as type name, e.g. for the parameter type or `T*` for the member variable pointer type. Then create `upclass<class1>` and `upclass<class2>` objects. Then only if they (the different templated upscale types) have to be more compatible (e.g. to be stored in a container), you would need a (common) base class for upscale with a virtual interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly write "store one of these" via `std::variant` and obtain the actual type (when needed) through `std::visit`:

```
#include <variant>

using class12 = std::variant<class1*, class2*>;

class upclass {
public:
    upclass(class12 argclass): myclass{argclass} {
        visit([](auto classn) { classn->init(); }, myclass);
    }
    void domorestuff() {
        visit([](auto classn) { classn->dostuff(); }, myclass);
    }
private:
    class12 myclass;
};
```

If those `visit`s get too repetitive, you might consider writing a pretty API to hide them:

```
class prettyclass12: public std::variant<class1*, class2*> {
private: // both g++ and clang want variant_size<>, a quick hack:
    auto& upcast() { return static_cast<std::variant<class1*, class2*>&>(*this); }
public:
    using std::variant<class1*, class2*>::variant;
    void init() { visit([](auto classn) { classn->init(); }, upcast()); }
    void dostuff() { visit([](auto classn) { classn->dostuff(); }, upcast()); }
};

class prettyupclass {
public:
    prettyupclass(prettyclass12 argclass): myclass{argclass} { myclass.init(); }
    void domorestuff() { myclass.dostuff(); }
private:
    prettyclass12 myclass;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say, this is a wide field and there are really many many possible solution.

But I guess that we are talking about object- oriented programming, derivation and plymorphic functions. What you describe, will be typically solved with a class hierachy.

You have one base class with virtual (polymorphic) functions.

Then you derive other classes from this base class and override the virtual functions from the base class.

In a 3rd step, you create some instances of the derived classes dynamically, during runtime and you store the newly created classes (their address) in a pointer to the **base** class.

Later, you can call any of the virtual overriden function through the base class pointer. And mechanism behind the scenes will call the correct function for you.

---

Additionally. You defined some function `init`. Such a function name suggests the usage of a class-constructor. This will be called automatically in the correct sequence. First the base class constructor and then the derived class constructor.

Please see the below example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base {
    std::string baseName{};
public:
    Base() {        // Do initialization stuff
        baseName = "Base";
        std::cout << "\nConstructor Base\n";
    }
    virtual void doStuff() {     // virtual function
        std::cout << baseName << '\n';
    }
};
class Derived1 : public Base {
    std::string derivedName{};
public:
    Derived1() : Base() {         // Do initialization stuff
        derivedName = "Derived1";
        std::cout << "Constructor Derived1\n";
    }
    void doStuff() override {       // Override virtaul function
        std::cout << derivedName << '\n';
    }
};
class Derived2 : public Base {
    std::string derivedName{};
public:
    Derived2() : Base() {        // Do initialization stuff 
        derivedName = "Derived2";
        std::cout << "Constructor Derived2\n\n";
    }
    void doStuff() override {       // Override virtaul function
        std::cout << derivedName << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    Base* base = new Base();

    Base* derived1 = new Derived1(); // Store in base class pointer
    Base* derived2 = new Derived2(); // Store in base class pointer

    base->doStuff();
    derived1->doStuff(); // Magic of polymorphism
    derived2->doStuff(); // Magic of polymorphism
}
```

The Base class pointer will accept all classes derived from Base.

Please note. In reality you ould not use raw pointers and also to the constructor differently. This is just fotr demo.

But, you need to read several books about it to get the complete understanding.

Comment: The Problem is: i did not write these classes. All i know is that they have the same methods. Thank you anyway.